# angularjs: $watch on a collection triggers 'out of memory' exception

Tags: angularjs

I want a button to be disabled whenever the property IsSelected of all the objects in a collection is set to false.

To deep watch a collection for taking action when a property changes, I do:

```
$scope.$watch('messages', function (i) {
       //do something
}, true);
```

But the collection is too big (actually I only have two elements but these are big objects) an d I run in a 'out of memory' exception.

So, what should I do instead ?

**[EDIT]**

following @boxed suggestion:

```
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $($scope.messages).map(function () {
                return this.IsSelected;
            });

        }, function (e) {
            //do something
        });
```

It is still very slow and I run into the error:

- Erreur d’exécution JavaScript: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Comment: if you just want to watch addition and deletion of objects from collectionn then you can watch 'messages.length'

Comment: Can you make a shadow version of the objects with just the items you need to watch?

Answer (score 2):

The first argument to $watch can be a function. In that function you can return a list of all the IsSelected properties of all the items.

Comment: I've tried that solution but I get an error an it is extremely slow. And for some reason the code for watching is triggered countless time during the page load. I've updated my code above. The error is  Erreur d’exécution JavaScript: 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!

Watchers fired in the last 5 iterations: [[],[],[],[],[]]

Comment: Well that sounds like some kind of progress anyway :P Maybe you should just have event handlers for when you change IsSelected instead, and there you loop through the items.

Comment: that's what I do, but the Angular way is more like watching things for changes, isn't it ?

Answer (score 0):

you can increase the digest limit 
https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$rootScopeProvider

```
        $rootScopeProvider.digestTtl(25);
```